Proof that the measure of a set is independent of its partition
I am struggling with writing and rigorousity and as an exercise from Terence Tao's Measure Theory book, I am trying to prove that the measure of a set E is independent of how it's partitioned.
My attempt is as below:
Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be an elementary set.
Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$.
$E = \cup^n_i A_i$ and $E = \cup^m_j B_j$ are two partitions of E where $A_i$ and $B_j$ are boxes for all $i = {1,..., n }$ and $j = {1,...,m}$
Therefore, we can write
$E=(\cup^n_i A_i ) \cap (\cup^m_j B_j )$
$E = \bigcup^{n,m}_{i,j} A_i \cap B_j$,
Therefore, each element of E is an intersection of boxes $A_i$ and $B_i$.
Let $m(E)$ denote the measure of E,
$m(E)=m(\bigcup^{n,m}_{i,j} A_i \cap B_j)$
by subadditivity:
$m(E) = \sum^{m,n}_{i,j} m(A_i \cap B_j)$
$m(E) = \sum^n_i|A_i|$ and $m(E) = \sum^m_j|B_j|$
so
$m(E) = \sum^{n}_{i} m(A_i \cap B_j) = \sum^m_j m(A_i \cap B_j)$
Therefore, m(E) is independent of the manner of partition of the set E.
Is this rigorous and how can I possibly improve my writing?

Your last equation cannot be right be right: the middle term has an unbound reference to $j$ and the right term has an unbound reference to $i$.  From $\sum_{i,j}^{m,n}$, you should expand, on the one hand, to $\sum_i^m \sum_j^n$ and on the other hand $\sum_j^n \sum_i^m$.

Thank you so much!
